# Build Peer Query with "Having Count" in Symfony 1.4

Tags: mysql, symfony-1.4, propel

I have a basic tagging system using the "Toxi" method. I have written a query which returns all posts which are tagged with ALL of a series of tags.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    media.*
FROM
    `post`, `post_tag_relation`, `post_tag`
WHERE
        AND post_tag_relation.post_tag_id = post_tag.id        
        AND (post_tag.id IN (211,215,214))
        GROUP BY post.id
        HAVING COUNT( post.id )=3
LIMIT 20;
```

However, I cannot convert this to Peer to include in my Symfony 1.4 app because the addHaving there appears to be no way to include a count for a having criteria through Peer.

If anyone has any info on converting this to Peer I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out for anyone else looking to do the same thing.

$having = $c->getNewCriterion(TablePeer::ID, 'COUNT('. TablePeer::ID . ') = ' . count($yourStuff), Criteria::CUSTOM); 
$c->addHaving($having);